How to use a Wi-Fi router for AirPlay from iPhone to Roku TV while iPhone streams video via cell data?
I am looking for advice on how to configure a Wi-Fi router without internet, in order for my iPhone to use AirPlay to watch streaming services on a Roku smart TV. When I set up the router using the default settings, and try to use AirPlay the iPhone apps will say that I don't have a connection.
I read a suggestion on another thread that said to change the IP address from automatic to manual on the iPhone by clicking on the small i next to the Wi-Fi connection. Then changing the IP address to 10.0.1.4 and sub-net to 255.255.0.0. I believe the suggestion was to let the iPhone know that this connection does not have internet. There must be a range of IP's that devices understand as not having internet?
I tried the above suggestion, but it did not work. I also tried to set up the router with the same IP address ranges. Does anyone have other suggestions on how to accomplish this?

FWIW, this is possible with Apple TV hardware because Apple's products support AWDL, "Apple Wireless Direct Link", which is kind of like an improved version of Wi-Fi Direct, or an early version of Wi-Fi Aware. It allows two devices with Wi-Fi radios to find each other and AirDrop/AirPlay even if they aren't on the same Wi-Fi network. But when you put the iPhone on a Wi-Fi network, it expects that Wi-Fi network to be its primary Internet connection. I have a feeling that what you're looking for will not be possible. The idea of magic IP subnets with special meaning sounds like an urban legend.
